# classic vowel exercise. I can't figure out why my for loop isn't working

Tags: javascript, html

The exercise problem- Write a function translate() that will translate a text into "rövarspråket". That is, double every consonant and place an occurrence of "o" in between. For example, translate("this is fun") should return the string "tothohisos isos fofunon".

I don't understand why my code doesn't work.

```
var word = prompt("Enter a word");

var vowels = ["a", "e", "i" ,"o", "u"];
var output;

for (var i=0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if (word.charAt(i) != "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u" ) {
        output = word.charAt(i) + "o" + word.charAt(i);    
    } else {
        output = word.charAt(i);   
    }
    document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = output;
}
```

Comment: `if (word.charAt(i) != "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u" ) {` is incorrect - you can't compare a variable to multiple values in one go. Why aren't you using your vowel array?

Comment: That's not how you do multiple comparisons.

Comment: hmmm okay I did not realize that. I will retry it with an array. Thanks.

Comment: `var output = '';` ... `output = output + ...;`

Comment: Your output variable will get reset every time the loop increases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
var word = prompt("Enter a word");

var vowels = ["a", "e", "i" ,"o", "u"];
var output;

for (var i=0; i < word.length; i++) {
 if (vowels.indexOf(word.charAt(i))==-1 ) {
     output += word.charAt(i) + "o" + word.charAt(i);    
 }
    else{
     output += word.charAt(i);   
    }
    document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = output;
}
```

Notice that i replaced the word.charAt(i) with vowels.indexOf
By using indexOf you can determin if something exists in an array by the returned value.indexof returns -1 if an element doesnot exist or the index of the element inside the array

Comment: `output = output + ...;`

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
if (word.charAt(i) != "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u" ) {...}
```

means

If [ `(word.charAt(i) !="a")` or `"e"` or `"a"` ... ]

And "e" evaluates as true when cast as boolean.

The correct code to do what you're trying to do would be

```
if (word.charAt(i) != "a") && (word.charAt(i) != "e")  && (word.charAt(i) != "i")  && (word.charAt(i) != "o")  && (word.charAt(i) != "u") ) {...}
```

In addition, change both the `output =` commands to `output+=`

Comment: So: if (word.charAt(i) != "a" || "e" is the same as: if (word.charAt(i) != "a" || true?

Comment: Yes, basically that's right. So the if condition will always evaluate as true as you wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved in **one line** with regex :

```
yourString.replace(/([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz])/g, '$1o$1'); // Add the accepted characters here
```

In your example :

```
"this is fun".replace(/([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz])/g, '$1o$1')
```

Outputs

```
"tothohisos isos fofunon"
```

Comment: your method is very good thanks. I was being stubborn and trying to figure out the OR operator.